# GitLab CE Installation takes too long to respond

Tags: installation, centos-7, gitlab

Currently I am trying to install gitlab community edition in CentOS 7. I followed the instructions provided by this [site](https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-configure-gitlab-on-centos-7/) to do it.

Everything seems to run ok, except from the installation which takes ages. [image: Installation screen of gitlab].

How can i find the status of the installation (log files, etc), to verify if there is a problem or not?

Please keep in mind the following:
I have not firewalld service on my machine.

Comment: 10 minutes is hardly "ages". Just keep a look on things. I have to wonder why you'd not just follow the [official documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-6).

Comment: It takes an hour and does not respond. I will follow your recommendation and I let you know.

Comment: At what point in your screenshot does that become apparent? It only shows a 2 minute/6 minute download?

Comment: Your link helped me a lot. I haven't figured out what the root cause was, but the only step that was missing in the process was the following command: chkconfig postfix on. So thank you for providing me the link.